# Remove annoucement for a specific user

Tags: event-receivers

Does anyone know how can I remove a list item for a current user when a checkbox is set to 'yes'? I have an announcement list and I want to hide a read announcement from the list, whenever the user sets the "archive" checkbox value to "yes", without the announcement disappearing from other users' list. can it be realized with an event receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view for your announcements list where Archive is equal to No. Use this view in a list view web part on your desired page and it will show only active posts.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom web part for displaying list items depending on the logged in user. An event receiver won't get you there.

This means you will need to programmatically create a view and feed it with a special query to get only items, the current user should see.